# Использование Google Translation API в расширении для Chrome

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Задача написать расширение для браузера Google Chrome, которое должно переводить на определённом сайте сообщения чата. То есть переводится не вся страничка, а лишь текстовое содержимое конкретного контейнера div. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup

Comment: Документацию я посмотрел первым делом. Есть ли способ не создавать проект и использовать сервис бесплатно?

Comment: Например как это делает сайт Google Переводчика или расширение.